# Static vs Dynamic Endpoints in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am wondering what is the purpose of Dynamic Endpoints in the ESB. I cannot figure out the documentation that clearly explains what it is for.

Also, I cannot understand the pros / cons of pushing the endpoints as "registry's resources".

They looks exactly the same as when I create them directly in the GUI

Does anyone have a pointer for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic endpoints are useful when you have multiple environments. Say you develop an proxy API in ESB, with an endpoint named EP1 saved in registry. Now, in your dev environment registry you have EP1 defined pointing to your dev backend URL. Once you move your proxy API to production, it will use the EP1 of prod registry. So you don't need to change your proxy API at all. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: well, a bit, that looks interesting, could you please provide a real example?

Comment: Here is a Sample https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+10%3A+Introduction+to+Dynamic+Endpoints+with+the+Registry